# What is this usage of 振り幅?

Tags: reading-comprehension

Two lovers had a fight. After some time, character A comes back to his lover and says this

> 別れたくない

To which the girl answers:

> えー　なんでそうなるんだよ!? これくらいで別れたりしないし!

And he answers to her:

> でも怒っているんだろう

so she answers him:

> 振り幅広すぎない!?

I understand the exchange is like

"I did not want to break up"

"Eh? Why would we break up for something like that?"

"But you were mad, were you not?"

But I don't quite understand the final answer. She's commenting his range of emotions is too vast?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, this 振り幅 refers to his range of emotions. He appeared too aggressive a while ago, and now he seems too weak and inconfident; that's what made her say 振り幅が大きい.

In general, 振り幅 (or 振れ幅) commonly refers to a wide variety of one's styles, abilities, emotions, etc. For example, 振り幅の大きい作家 refers to a writer with a wide range of styles. 感情の振り幅が大きい人 describes someone who frequently fluctuates between intense joy, madness and deep sadness.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that 振り幅 often means 感情の振り幅, which means 'range of emotions' (I don't know if this makes complete sense in English, but it is basically used to express someone's unstable psychological state as 感情の振り幅が大きい).

However, I guess in the quoted context it simply refers to a logical leap in the boy's reasoning. That is, thinking that they need to break up just because she was mad seemed a logical jump to the girl. Literally, "the width between her being mad and necessity of breaking up is too great".

Comment: 飛躍した議論や突飛な連想を指して「振り幅が広い」と言うことは普通ないと思いますが…。単純にさっきは怒っていて今は逆に弱々し過ぎるというギャップを指摘しているのではと思います。